# How to avoid obstruction of supposedly parallel sun light?

Tags: lighting

I am trying to make a Solar System scene. An obvious lighting for this scene is the "Sun" light, but it is obstructed by a big object even when the position of the light is outside that big object, as illustrated with the following images:
[image: with "Sun" object]

This is how it should look
[image: Without sun object]

This are the position of two sun lights, both outside the big object.
[image: Position of the "Sun" lights.]

First, I don't get why this happens since the lights are located and pointing outside the big object.  Second, I'll appreciate any suggestion to solve this problem. Blender 2.8.7.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Hello :). Sun light is different from other lights. It only has a direction. No matter where you put it, it'll always shine from infinite distance.

Comment: Jachym, I know, exactly that is the reason I am using it for this simulation. That doesn't explain why it is affected by a nearby object outside its way.

Comment: Ok, I was not really understanding Sun light. You were right, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 'Sun' lamp is so called because it simulates the light of the sun as perceived *on Earth*.

Its rays are parallel, from infinity. It has no position, and so no falloff with distance. (Good for you, in that respect.) The position of the lamp's gizmo has no bearing on its effect; only its direction makes any difference. All objects will cast shadows on other objects 'behind' them *in that direction*.

A quick solution to your problem, either in Cycles or EEVEE, would be to use one Sun lamp, anywhere you like, (inside the Sun object if that seems logical) pointing parallel to the Sun > Planet direction, and with 'Cast Shadow' or 'Shadow' switched off in the lamp's *Properties* panel > *Data* tab.

This would also mean planets do not cast shadows on one another.

If you want more particular effects, the answer will vary, depending on your renderer. For example, if you're in Cycles, you may want to prevent planets bouncing light on to one another, using a *Light Path* node. Or if you wanted the planets to go round the sun, you could use a shadowless point-lamp at the sun's position, with its falloff adjusted if necessary.

Comment: That solved it, just turn off Shadows!  Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @user2309000 Great!